# align image randomized by function

Tags: javascript, image, function

This part of code works alright:

```
var cobras=new Array();

cobras[0] = '<img src="Cobra1.jpg">';
cobras[1] = '<img src="Cobra2.jpg">';
cobras[2] = '<img src="Cobra3.jpg">';
cobras[3] = '<img src="Cobra4.jpg">';
cobras[4] = '<img src="Cobra5.jpg">';
cobras[5] = '<img src="Cobra6.jpg">';
cobras[6] = '<img src="Cobra7.jpg">';
cobras[7] = '<img src="Cobra8.jpg">';
cobras[8] = '<img src="Cobra9.jpg">';
cobras[9] = '<img src="Cobra10.jpg">';
cobras[10] = '<img src="Cobra11.jpg">';
cobras[11] = '<img src="Cobra12.jpg">';
cobras[12] = '<img src="Cobra13.jpg">';
cobras[13] = '<img src="Cobra14.jpg">';
cobras[14] = '<img src="Cobra15.jpg">';
var numberChosen=Math.floor(Math.random()*15); 

function makeDisappear() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("main");
    elem.style.visibility = "hidden";
    var elem = document.getElementById("empty");
    elem.style.visibility = "visible";

    var bodyE1 = document.body;
    bodyE1.innerHTML += cobras[numberChosen];
}
```

But it adds an image aligned to the left, and I want to align it at center. Here's what I've tried:

```
var bodyE2 = document.getElementById("parte");
bodyE2.innerHTML = cobras[numberChosen];
```

And here's how I call it:

```
<center> 
    <img id="parte" src=" ' + cobras[numberChosen] +  ' ">
</center>
```

But the image doesn't appear, and if I inspect the element, there's is something like `img src="Cobras7"` "inside" the image part, like:

```
\/ <img id = "parte" src=" ' + cobras[numberChosen] + ' "> 
        <img src="Cobras7">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I know that the error is that it goes like img id="parte" src = " <img src="Cobra11".jpg>" but how to do it in another way?

Comment: You should create a time machine to deliver those `<center>` tags back to 1999. Just set the margin to `0 auto` and position relative in the CSS, and once you have valid markup the image will be centered !

Comment: I've started html on Friday, so the simpler the better... They've worked alright. Anyway, how to set that margin ? - done